# Second derivative test using $f_{yy}$ instead of $f_{xx}$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, maxima-minima

The second derivative test for functions of two variables says to first find critical points. For each critical point one finds
$$
D = f_{xx}f_{yy} - f_{xy}^2
$$
If $D>0$, the sign of $f_{xx}$ says something about whether the point is a local maximum or local minimum.

My question is: Why do we use $f_{xx}$? Could we use $f_{yy}$ instead?

Comment: If $D>0$ they have the same sign, so yes.

Comment: +1 for curiosity & symmetry observation!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are assuming that $D >0$.  This says that
$$
f_{xx}f_{yy} > f_{xy}^2 \geq 0.
$$
Hence either both $f_{xx}, f_{yy}$ are positive together or negative together.  Since they have the same sign, the test works either way.